# Android WiFi sending and receiving information

Tags: java, android, wifi

Sorry for kind of a dummy question, but I'm wondering how to work with WiFi connection via android. My application needs to transfer some data (both receiving and sending) with PC or with other android device using WiFi. How should I organize the process? I mean, how should I establish connection, then should I open a socket for data transfering, etc. Is there any way to do it without internet connection, smth like bluetooth, except wifi.p2p (which is only available for android 4.0)? Would be grateful for as detailed manual as possible.

Comment: may be not well formulated but interesting question

Comment: I'm interested in technical details, f.e. is there something special about creating socket via android, what special methods are available to receive/send data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Every network connection even if only in the local network or localhost reqieres the INTERNET permission.

Bluetooth and NFC might be an option, but I have no experiance with that.